# Is it possible to display result of Rg into quick fix window?

Tags: vim, ripgrep, vim-quickfix

When i am searching `:Rg <string>` , it is opening the result in FZF buffer. Often the filenames are not displayed fully in it. Also the once escaped the results are gone. I have to do research if need to check the same word again.

but `:vim /pattern/g **/*` opens the result in quickfix. Is there any way to open Rg result in quickfix window? How to display the full file name in Rg buffer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can tell Vim what external command to use for `:help :grep` with `:help 'grepprg'`.

Comment: There is a confusion in adding grepprg. Whether this use Rg only for :grep command or also for :vimgrep command.

Comment: Only `:grep` is concerned by `:help 'grepprg'` but both `:help :grep` and `:help :vimgrep` have the exact same relationship with the quickfix list.

Comment: I don't understand this answer!

Comment: @RizaKhan what, specifically, do you not understand?

Comment: Nevermind I figured it out. I'll post an answer

Comment: @RizaKhan what was the answer? I have a very similar problem (I’d like to use FZF for search, but also be able to populate the quickfix list with the results)

Comment: @fanaugen Here is what I use:  `set grepprg=rg\ -i\ --vimgrep`

Answer (score 11):

I have my `:Rg` results open in a popover and that allows me to cycle through the results using `<Ctrl>j` and `<Ctrl>k`.

That is an individual selection though so if you want to save your results to a quick fix list, start by `<Tab>` and you will noticed a red indicator show up next to the name. Once you press enter everything with the indicator will be placed in the quick fix list.

[image]

[image]

I also wanted to mention my function for Rg

```
" Ripgrep advanced
function! RipgrepFzf(query, fullscreen)
  let command_fmt = 'rg --column --line-number --no-heading --color=always --smart-case %s || true'
  let initial_command = printf(command_fmt, shellescape(a:query))
  let reload_command = printf(command_fmt, '{q}')
  let spec = {'options': ['--phony', '--query', a:query, '--bind', 'change:reload:'.reload_command]}
  call fzf#vim#grep(initial_command, 1, fzf#vim#with_preview(spec), a:fullscreen)
endfunction

command! -nargs=* -bang RG call RipgrepFzf(<q-args>, <bang>0)
```

And I also wanted to add some shortcuts for quickfix list so that you can cycle through them easily:

```
map <leader>cc :botright cope<cr>
map <leader>co ggVGy:tabnew<cr>:set syntax=qf<cr>pgg
" Next item on list
map <leader>n :cn<cr>
" Previous item on list
map <leader>p :cp<cr>
```

Comment: The <tab> to select results from Rg to be put in quick-fix windows is a breeze!

Comment: Is there a way to save **all** results from `Rg` to the quickfix list?

Comment: @fanaugen did you ever figure out how to save all results from Rg to quickfix list?

Comment: @azizj not really; I’m using the tab key to add only selected results to the quickfix list